# Need Assistance With Page Please

Tags: facebook, hyperlink

I have a facebook page - facebook.com/ThriftyDealsOnline

Now, I've added my link to my business website at thriftydealsonline.com

My problem is that when a visitor clicks on the link, it does send them to facebook but only to the basic signup/login page.

Other sites that I have visited and have a facebook link, takes you to the facebook signup/login page but it shows their cover photo, number of likes, etc.  Of course the visitor has to signup/login to view their entire page but mine doesn't do this and I'm fearing that I'm losing FB likes because of it.

As an example, visit: http://www.143kids.com - they have a FB link which is http://www.facebook.com/usedkidsclothes - You'll see that when you click on their link, it shows their cover photo as well as some info.

Can someone help me figure out why this is happening?

Comment: The links work just fine for me.  I click on the link on your .com page and it takes me to your facebook page, and I click the link on your facebook page it and it takes me to your .com page.

Comment: your page is not reachable even when i am logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your fan page is not on facebook,I try to find your profile and do not show up on facebook, you can do this: login to your profile and see your profile name in the address bar copy and paste it in a text file close your session and paste the link into the address bar again to see what happens, if you see a profile that is  paste on your website.

Comment: I'm on my FB page right now... the link is http://www.facebook.com/ThriftyDealsOnline so I'm a little confused at to why you say its not on facebook?  If you do a search for my page via the FB search bar, its under ThriftyDealsOnline.com

Comment: try this go to [link](http://www.facebook.com/username/) here you can see the name that has your fanpage  or can put that you wish

Comment: I did as you said and here is a screen shot of what it tells me... http://www.thriftydealsonline.com/v/vspfiles/images/fbpage.jpg

Comment: ok I see, do this select your fanpage, as you can see you can type a new name,  putt all in lowercase and see what happens when you make click on your new name this should be send to your fanpage...

Comment: Unfortunately, I had already edited/changed my username once and it won't let me do it again.  So are you telling me that just because there are uppercase letters that this is why I'm having the problem?  Thanks for your help btw... I really appreciate it.

Comment: I was able to figure out the problem... it was the country restrictions that were preventing it from showing up.  Thanks for your assistance.